# Thinkfan refuses to run

Tags: startup, thinkpad, fan

Thinkfan won't run on startup, but I can make it run with the command systemctl start thinkfan.service. Running a status check on it to see if it's running after rebooting gives me this error:

```
root@ThinkPad-T470:/home/mickbeck# systemctl status thinkfan.service

● thinkfan.service - simple and lightweight fan control program

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-12-08 19:37:43 CST; 2min 7s ago

  Process: 815 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thinkfan (code=exited, status=4)


Dec 08 19:37:43 ThinkPad-T470 systemd[1]: Starting simple and lightweight fan control program...

Dec 08 19:37:43 ThinkPad-T470 thinkfan[815]: thinkfan 0.9.1 starting...

Dec 08 19:37:43 ThinkPad-T470 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=4

Dec 08 19:37:43 ThinkPad-T470 systemd[1]: Failed to start simple and lightweight fan control program.

Dec 08 19:37:43 ThinkPad-T470 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Unit entered failed state.

Dec 08 19:37:43 ThinkPad-T470 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What gives?

Also thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I got it working by removing the virtual temp levels from my /etc/thinkfan.conf file.

Not sure if this is going to be a problem, just having coretemp lvls. But it works